# Is the number of Client-Side requests for Google Custom Search API limited?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, google-search-api

I've an account with [Google Developers](https://console.developers.google.com), where it shows that the limit is `1,000 requests/day` for a specific API key. My question is, is this the number of requests by the server or the client side?

Currently, I'm using the [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/)

`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&hl=en&gl=en&userip=&q=test+imdb&start=0&rsz=8`

for making AJAX requests by client and display it.None of my code is server side. Which seems to work fine. But the results arn't up to date and clearly, it might be completely removed from service anytime soon.

I'm also using the USER-IP parameter while using that API to make sure google knows how is requesting how many times. So, can I make as many client side requests as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit 10.000/month is per-app (per-client) as you are using it with your key, so it doesnt matter does the client start the calls because they are on behalf of your app

Comment: Is there any way, I can make a client side request without the client having no request limit?

Comment: its not possible with custom search, you'd have to redirect clients in another window to https://www.google.pl/?q=test where test is what they're searching

Comment: The clients only happen to use the API as javascript

Comment: then you have to have the limit or pay for this sorry

Answer (score 0):

So firstly its 10,000 requests/day if you have paid API. if you send request from any client or server side it is consider as a request to google custom search api.